# codepen disables external image link

Tags: css, codepen

I'm using codepen normally, and I'm linking imgur images to imgur or GoogleDrive, they all work, but after a while they do not show up anymore, what could it be? Already configured for public access.

```
<https://codepen.io/Cleston/pen/zyxGdL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images from imgur.com do not work in CodePen, because they (Imgur) block the Referer from CodePen. The images display in your CodePen if they are cached by your browser. But eventually the cache will be deleted and your images won't show up anymore. You can verify that by looking at the network calls in you browser dev tools. The images get loaded with a status code `200 (from disk cache)`.

If you delete your cache (or open a new tab in incognito mode), you get a `403 Forbidden` when the browser tries to load the images, because imgur refuses to serve those images to CodePen.

Comment: which website in the cloud would you recommend to do this?